# Encoding a JMS TextMessage

Tags: character-encoding, jms

I'm receiving messages from a JMS MQ queue which are supposedly `utf-8` encoded. However on reading the out using `msgText = ((TextMessage)msg).getText();`
I get question marks where non standard characters were present. It seems possible to specify the encoding when using a `bytemessage`, but I cant find a way to specify encoding while reading out the `TextMessage`. Is there a way to solve this, or should I press for `bytemessages`?

Comment: Which JMS transport are you using ? Are you passing XML messages ? Which platform are you consuming and producing messages from/to ?

Comment: We're on Websphere MQ, the messages are XML with encoding="UTF-8"

Comment: I'm not sure which platform is producing but we're consuming With Websphere running on solaris. Unfortunately we're completely agnostic about the mq implementation so I cant give an version numbers at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We tried adding `Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"` to `Websphere`'s jvm and we added

```
source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
     ((TextMessage) msg).getText().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

In our `MessageListener`. This worked for us, so then we took out the `Dfile.encoding` bit away and it still works for us.

Due to preferred minimum configuration for `Websphere` we decided to leave it this way, also taking into account that we may easier switch the `UTF-8` string by a setting from file or database.

Comment: Thank you, dr jerry: Using StreamSource worked for us. Our XML message is read from the TIBCO JMS queue and then unmarshaled with JAXB API:    JAXBElement<ContentDetailType> jbElement = (JAXBElement<ContentDetailType>) ourJaxb2Marshaller
     .unmarshal(streamSource);

Comment: This is quite an unusual solution we would not think of right away - so thank you @dr-jerry !

Comment: for me, adding `Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"` on the receiving end solved the issue

Comment: @leo7r This issue shows up even with `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"` on the receiver's side

Answer (score 2):

If the text is not decoded correctly, then probably the client is not sending the message with the utf-8 codec; this should work:

```
byte[] by = ((TextMessage) msg).getText().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String text = new String(by,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: This didn't work for us. What did work was using the StreamSource class as dr jerry figured out.